# v4l2loopback on surface devices

Tags: release-hera, webcam, surface-tablet

I'm newbie with Elementary OS, and I really enjoying the speed and stability of the OS.
The only thing that it's really annoying for me is the webcam and videoconferencing software with my Surface device, so I planned to install "Iriun Webcam" in order to use my cellphone camera as webcam and workaround the current limitations.

v4l2loopback is required to create a virtual video device in order to map to cellphone cam.

First problem: v4l2loopback version (0.10) in Elementary repository is outdated and incompatible with kernel 5.x.
To solve, I downloaded, compiled, and loaded the module to kernel but it seems to be not working.

**My video devices BEFORE modprobe**

```
**$ ls -ltrh /dev/video**
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video0 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video3 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 8 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video4 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video8 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video6 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video9 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video10 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video7 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 9 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video5 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video11 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video13 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video12

**$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2**
$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 8 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video9
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 9 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16 Jun 23 07:22 /dev/video12
**crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 21 Jun 23 09:59 /dev/video15**
**crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 20 Jun 23 09:59 /dev/video14**
```

As you see above, the video devices has been created, but any application "see" the devices.
Iriunweb app says: "initialization failed. You may want to run sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1"

Any help?

Is there anybody using 5.1 with surface book device?

My Environment

Hardware model: Surface Book 1

Kernel version: 5.7.4-surface (github/linux-surface)

Distribution: 5.1 Elementary OS

Comment: I have found this: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/134 The problem is that I am not familiar. You can try commands mentioned there.

Comment: Solution from here you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508743/unable-to-route-webcam-video-to-virtual-video-device-on-linux-via-opencv

Comment: I'll give a try to this solutions but, I have very low skills in linux OS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Finally solved my problem using Droidcam software. I've found better optimized for Linux systems than Iriunwebcam.
**Now, I can make Gogole Meet videocalls using my phone as webcam in a Surface book device.**
The recipe:

- Elementary OS 5.1 Hera
- Surface-linux Kernel (https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface)
- v4l2loopback 0.12.5 (https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)
- Droidcam (https://www.dev47apps.com/)

I hope this helps.
Thank you!